# My code has hundreds of instances of repeated equality checks - how can I simplify this?

Tags: c#

The problem looks like I've had about 500 files with `if` statements looking like the one I have below. How might I replace these `if` statements without manually overwriting them each by each?

The `if` statement below returns a null reference exception if _azon is null so that is the main reason behind the replacement of the if statements.

```
 string _azon;
 public string azon
 {
     get { return _azon; }
     set {
         if (((_azon == null) && (value != null)) || !_azon.Equals(value)) {
              _azon = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's worth it to even do these checks?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with, exactly?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel To evade NullReferenceException, each if statement would look like this: if ((_kod == null) && (value != null)) {

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils These checks help us minimize requests for a database since all of these are part of an entity-based framework.

Comment: You could write a small function with a `ref` parameter on the `_azon` part.  If there are multiple types (i.e., not just strings), you could make it generic in `T` where `T: class, IEquatable`

Comment: Oh, come on.  Other than poor phasing "what is the best way", this really isn't opinion-based.  Would it have closed if the question was "How can I replace these IF statements, I have hundreds of them?".  Voting to re-open

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to change the code to work better or do you already know how you want the code and you want to automate the change? If it's the second one, then you can do multi-file regular expression find-and-replace using VisualStudio.

Comment: @Jack A. the goal is to automate the procedure, find and replace doesn't work sadly as the variable name is something else on each file.

Comment: I've answered as well as I can based on the question and comments. It would be helpful if you would edit your question to make it clearer. If you could give clear examples of "I want to replace X with Y", that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and the code snippet in one of your comments, my understanding is that you want to replace this:

```
if (((_azon == null) && (value != null)) || !_azon.Equals(value)) {
```

with this:

```
if ((_azon == null) && (value != null)) {
```

You can do that with the [Capture groups and replacement patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#capture-groups-and-replacement-patterns) feature in VisualStudio. You need to capture your variable name and use a replacement pattern to substitute it in the replacement string. Capturing the variable name is easy enough using the `\w` character class.

So your search expression would be:

```
if \(\(\((\w+) == null\) && \(value != null\)\) \|\| !\w+\.Equals\(value\)\) {
```

and your replacement pattern would be:

```
if (($1 == null) && (value != null)) {
```

Note the `(\w+)` in the search expression captures your variable, and the `$1` in the replacement pattern substitutes it into the replacement text.

I find this site very useful for creating and testing regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

To do [multi-file replacement in VisualStudio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/replace-in-files?view=vs-2022), you bring up the search dialog with the menu using "Edit/Find and Replace/Replace in Files" or use the Ctrl+Shift+H hotkey. On that dialog, you need to check the "Use regular expressions" checkbox.

Comment: I still think you are better off with a worker function that does the work for you (like the `SetIfNeeded` I showed in my answer).

Comment: @Flydog57 Agreed. And now he knows how to fix it when he comes around to that solution.

Comment: And, in particular, if he/she decides to change the logic after a refactor like I proposed, it's all in one place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method is implemented something like this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
{  
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You could write a function that looks something like:

```
private void SetIfNeeded<T>(T value, ref T prop, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") where T: class, IEquatable<T>
{
    if ((prop == null && value != null) || !prop.Equals(value))
    {
        prop = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

and then consume in within your property setters this way:

```
string _azon;
public string azon
{
    get { return _azon; }
    set {
            SetIfNeeded(value, ref _azon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if both prop and value are null though?

Comment: Sorry for the poor phrasing, I'm looking to automate the procedure not simplify it.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang: I just copied the logic from the OP's post.  If they are both null, then there is no use doing the `Set`.  The point of this is to not bother with the `Set` unless there is a real change (since a `Set` will cause a database update) - I think